# Дерево каталогов - подсчитать количество вложенных каталогов на каждом из уровней

Tags: python, файловая-система, дерево, ос

Как можно, используя `python`, в частности `os.walk()` (хотя возможно и не только эту функцию?), подсчитать количество вложенных каталогов на каждом из уровней?

Т.е., например, есть такая структура:

```
A\B1\C1
....\C2
....\C3
.\B2\D1
....\D2
.\B3\E1
```

Хочется в итоге иметь значения количества директорий для каждого уровня:

```
num1 == [1]
num2 == [3]
num3 == [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Какие у вас сложности возникли с использованием `os.walk()`? Попробуйте словарь: имя папки -> количество вложенных папок: `{dirpath: len(dirs) for dirpath, dirs, _ in os.walk(rootdir)}`

Comment: Тут проблема с тем, какую структуру данных в итоге надо получить. Дерево папок получить просто: `def foo: return {f: foo(join(path, f)) for f in [f for f in listdir(path) if isdir(join(path, f))]}`, длина каждого словаря - искомое число, но как представить дерево в виде списка (списка списков).

Comment: Словарь `{dirpath: len(dirs) for dirpath, dirs, _ in os.walk(rootdir)}` -- хорошая идея, но всё же я не понимаю, как его дальше преобразовать к нужному мне виду. Ведь в `dirpath` будет перечисление _всех_ директорий, содержащихся в `rootdir`, причем, в чем и загвоздка - не единожды.

Comment: @Дмитрий: 1- что является *"нужным мне виду"*? Руками писать num1, num2, num3 не работает для любой директории, в которой не три вложенных папки. Зачем вам вообще списки num1, num2, num3? как вы их хотите использовать? 2- *"причем, в чем и загвоздка - не единожды."* -- это невозможно сразу по двум причинам (любой одной достаточно): ключи в словарях уникальны и os.walk() каждый dirpath только однажды выдаёт.

Comment: @jfs Нужный вид -- это список списков, длина внешнего списка -- максимальная глубина вложенности директорий начиная с указанной корневой, а внутренние списки должны содержать количество _папок_, содержащихся на уровень ниже. Для приведённой в вопросе директории `A` ответом будет `[[1], [3], [3, 2, 1]]`.

Comment: @jfs Сложность для меня в том, что используя цикл `for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir)` мне не удается идентифицировать каждый из уровней дерева каталогов. А вид данных я выбрал такой, потому что поставленная задача сводится к отысканию максимума -- нужно найти максимальное значение вложенных папок в каждой их папок текущего уровня.

Comment: Если бы сюда можно было прицепить картинку -- было бы проще. Смотрите: пусть в папке `A` содержатся папки `B1`, `B2`, `B3`, в папке `B1` содержится папка `C1`, в папке `B2` вложенных папок нет, в папке `B3` содержатся папки `D1`, `D2`. Тогда максимальное значение вложенных папок на 1-м уровне будет 3, на 2-м уровне -- `max{1; 0; 2} == 2`. Надеюсь, я понятно изложил.

Comment: Я надеюсь, что вы понимаете, результаты, которые получатся, — гораздо чаще правильные, но могут быть и нет. Причём это касается и всех ответов здесь на текущий момент.

Comment: @0andriy если вы знаете случай когда код из [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/730106/23044) не работает, то оставьте комментарий под самим ответом, чтобы его можно было бы улучшить (или объяснить почему получаемый результат правильный)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы посчитать количество дочерних папок на каждом уровне вложенности, удобно рекурсивную функцию использовать, чтобы легко текущую глубину (`depth`) отслеживать:

```
def get_nested_counts(rootdir):
    def count_subdirs(dirs, depth):
        if len(counts) == depth:
            counts.append([])  # add new deeper level
        counts[depth].append(len(dirs))
        for path in dirs:
            subdirs = [entry for entry in os.scandir(path)
                       if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False)]
            if subdirs:  # if there are subdirs
                count_subdirs(subdirs, depth + 1)  # make recursive call

    counts = []
    count_subdirs([rootdir], 0)
    return counts
```

К примеру, для структуры директорий из вопроса:

```
$ tree -d A
A
├── B1
│   ├── C1
│   ├── C2
│   └── C3
├── B2
│   ├── D1
│   └── D2
└── B3
    └── E1
```

```py
>>> get_nested_counts('A')
[[1], [3], [2, 1, 3]]
```

Порядок обхода директорий на одном уровне не определён (что `os.scandir()` возвращает). Ноль (отсутствие дочерних папок) не записывается.

Comment: Обход каталогов -- неатомарная операция  почти на любой ФС. Чтобы гарантировать консистентный результат, надо цепляться к сервису типа inotify. Обратите внимание на слово *консистентный*. Т.е. он не может быть 100% правильным, но очень часто может совпадать с правильным (в учебных случаях думаю до 99.99999% вероятности).

Comment: @0andriy о семи девятках, не зная точной задачи, бессмысленно говорить. В зависимости от задачи, можно начать с  добавления обработки ошибок (доступа), замены рекурсии на явный цикл. Если вас такие вещи как атомарность, consistency интересуют, то следует настоящую базу данных использовать с ACID транзакциями (A-atomicity, C—consistency) вместо файловой системы.

Comment: вы просили пример, когда ваш ответ даст неверный результат, я вам его привёл (любой параллельный процесс, который создаёт или удаляет каталоги внутри исследуемого).

Comment: @0andriy мы с вами по разному задачу понимаем. Код работает как и ожидается. Ещё раз: в зависимости от фактической задачи, можно расширить его. Но учитывая постановку задачи в вопросе, это безумие говорить об атомарности, «консистентном результате», на данном этапе, а inotify здесь как седло на свинье полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Просто с помощью функции для понимания как это работает:

```
import os

def scan_dir(path):
    file_count = 0
    catalog_count = 0
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            file_count += 1
        else:
            catalog_count +=1
            scan_dir(file_path)
    print('[',path,']\n\t', 'files: %s' % file_count, 'catalogs: %s' % catalog_count)
```

С помощью os.walk() можно все вообще в 2 строчки уложить:

```
import os

src = 'C:\c'
for dir_name, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    print(dir_name, len(dirs))
```